# Rails 4 - Sanitize helper doesn't work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on Agile Rails 4 book.
I set up a Cloud9 work environment and after each iteration, I deploy the project to Heroku.

Here's the question: I use a sanitize helper to show my catalog. On my local server ( in cloud9) it works without any problem, but when I deploy to heroku, the helper doesn't work.

Example: When you sanitize, the output data is inside `<p>` tag. On heroku, tag `<p>` is not present.

```
- if notice
    %p.notice= notice

%h1 Your Pragmatic catalog
- cache ['store', Product.latest] do
    - @products.each do |product|
        -cache ['entry', product] do    
            .entry
                = image_tag(product.image_url)
                %h3= product.title
                = sanitize(product.description) 
                .price_line
                    %span.price= number_to_currency(product.price)
                    = button_to "Add to Cart", line_items_path(product_id: product)
```

Any ideas?